# Scanning Ruby on Rails Projects with SonarQube

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sonarqube, code-analysis

I want to check my Ruby on Rails app with sonarqube. I've added the Web plugin which should work with Ruby but I get the following error during sonarqube exectution:

```
app/controllers/course_statistics_controller.rb
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.sonar.UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.isUnsupportedTag(UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.java:77) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.web.checks.sonar.UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.startElement(UnsupportedTagsInHtml5Check.java:71) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scanElementTag(HtmlAstScanner.java:117) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scanElement(HtmlAstScanner.java:96) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scan(HtmlAstScanner.java:80) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.web.visitor.HtmlAstScanner.scan(HtmlAstScanner.java:59) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.plugins.web.core.WebSensor.analyse(WebSensor.java:93) ~[na:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:59) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:51) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.phases.DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.execute(DatabaseModePhaseExecutor.java:120) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:264) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:220) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:57) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:45) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:135) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:92) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:77) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:158) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.1.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch1741912612400004619.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_65]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53) [sonar-runner-dist-2.4.jar:na]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like SonarQube 7.4 now has support for Ruby!

[image: Ruby Ruby Analysis Has Arrived!]

https://www.sonarqube.org/sonarqube-7-4/

Answer (score 12):

SonarQube has dropped support for Ruby.

If you want to supply code styles check for your application, you take a look into following links:

[Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

[RuboCop](http://RuboCop%20-%20Ruby%20static%20code%20analyzer.%20Out%20of%20the%20box%20it%20will%20enforce%20many%20of%20the%20guidelines%20outlined%20in%20the%20community%20https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide.%20Very%20configurable%20and%20well%20maintained%20gem.%20I%20use%20it.%20%20Guard-ruboCop%20-%20allows%20you%20to%20automatically%20check%20Ruby%20code%20style%20with%20RuboCop%20when%20files%20are%20modified.%20%20Rails%20best%20practices%20-%20a%20code%20metric%20tool%20to%20check%20the%20quality%20of%20rails%20cod.%20Well%20maintained.%20I%20use%20it.%20%20Simplecov%20-%20code%20coverage%20analysis%20tool%20for%20Ruby%20(tests).%20I%20use%20it.%20%20Reek%20-%20%20is%20a%20tool%20that%20examines%20Ruby%20classes,%20modules%20and%20methods%20and%20reports%20any%20Code%20Smells%20it%20finds.%20I%20used%20it%20once.) - Ruby static code analyzer. Out of the box it will enforce many of the guidelines outlined in the community [rails-style-guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide). Very configurable and well maintained gem.

[Guard-ruboCop](http://RuboCop%20-%20Ruby%20static%20code%20analyzer.%20Out%20of%20the%20box%20it%20will%20enforce%20many%20of%20the%20guidelines%20outlined%20in%20the%20community%20https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide.%20Very%20configurable%20and%20well%20maintained%20gem.%20I%20use%20it.%20%20Guard-ruboCop%20-%20allows%20you%20to%20automatically%20check%20Ruby%20code%20style%20with%20RuboCop%20when%20files%20are%20modified.%20%20Rails%20best%20practices%20-%20a%20code%20metric%20tool%20to%20check%20the%20quality%20of%20rails%20cod.%20Well%20maintained.%20I%20use%20it.%20%20Simplecov%20-%20code%20coverage%20analysis%20tool%20for%20Ruby%20(tests).%20I%20use%20it.%20%20Reek%20-%20%20is%20a%20tool%20that%20examines%20Ruby%20classes,%20modules%20and%20methods%20and%20reports%20any%20Code%20Smells%20it%20finds.%20I%20used%20it%20once.) - allows you to automatically check Ruby code style with RuboCop when files are modified.

[Rails best practices](https://github.com/railsbp/rails_best_practices) - a code metric tool to check the quality of rails cod. Well maintained.

[Simplecov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) - code coverage analysis tool for Ruby (tests).

[Reek](https://github.com/troessner/reek) -  is a tool that examines Ruby classes, modules and methods and reports any Code Smells it finds.

Comment: @Felix no probs, these are really nice tools and you can set these according to your specifics.

Comment: Can I use  them  with  Jenkins?

Comment: @Felix Jenkins seems to be used with Ruby, so why not? :) rvm.io/integration/jenkins

Comment: I've tried to get working those. I've installed the Jenkins ruby metrics plugin but that dosn't work. The only thing I wanted is to do static code analyses of my projekt during a jenkins build job.

Answer (score 0):

https://ebertapp.io/  is a good option for rails code review